# G is a bipartite graph, where for every edge e=(a,b)[a,b are in A,B] d(a)>d(b), and d(a)>0, show that there is a matching saturating A

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

[image]

I think the direction is definitely HALL, i tried using induction on the size of S, where S is some subgroup of A, but i wasn't able to complete the process.

Answer (score 5):

We must prove that given $S \subseteq A$, the inequality $\left|S\right| \leq N(S)$ holds. The proof will be by induction on $\left|S\right|$, with the immediate base case.

Let $a \in S$ and $S' = S - a$. By the inductive hypothesis, $\left|S'\right| \leq \left|N\left(S'\right)\right|$. If $\left|S'\right| < \left|N\left(S'\right)\right|$, then $\left|S\right| = \left|S'\right| + 1 \leq \left|N\left(S'\right)\right| \leq \left|N\left(S\right)\right|$.

Now, suppose $\left|S'\right| = \left|N\left(S'\right)\right|$.

Our goal is to prove that $N(a) \not\subseteq N\left(S'\right)$; this way, we can ensure that

$$
\left|S'\right| = \left|N\left(S'\right)\right| < \left|N\left(S\right)\right| \Longrightarrow \left|S\right| = \left|S'\right| + 1 \leq \left|N\left(S\right)\right|.
$$

Assume then that $N(a) \subseteq N\left(S'\right)$. Let $S' = \{a_{1},\dots,a_{k}\}$ and $N(S) = N\left(S'\right) = \{b_{1},\dots,b_{k}\}$. Now, by inductive hypothesis, $S^\prime$ satisfies the Hall condition, and there exists a matching from $S^\prime$ to $N\left(S^\prime\right)$; let $a_{i}b_{i}$ be the edges of this matching. Thus, $\deg(a_{i})\ge\deg(b_{i})$.

Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum\deg(a_{i}) & < & \sum\deg(a_{i}) + \deg(a) \hspace{1cm}\text{because $\deg(a) > 0$}\\
 & \leq & \sum\deg(b_{i}) \hspace{2.45cm}\text{because $N(S) = N\left(S'\right)$}\\
 & \leq & \sum\deg(a_{i}). \hspace{2.3cm}\text{because $\deg(a_{i}) \geq \deg(b_{i})$}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is the following:

First prove a lemma:
If $G$ is a bipartite graph with bipartition $X,Y$ and no isolated vertices in $X$,
such that $d(x)\geq d(y)$ whenever $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ are adjacent.
Then $|X|\leq|Y|$.

Then for each subset $S$ of $A$ you find that the degree conditions still hold for the subgraph induced by $S\cup N(S)$. Now the lemma implies that $|S|\leq|N(S)|$ and you have verified Hall's condition.

You can prove the lemma by induction on the maximum degree.
Here are a few hints for the proof of the lemma.

Let $k$ be the maximum degree.
The induction base ($k=1$) is simple.
For the induction step, let $G$ be a smallest counterexample for the claim with maximum degree $k>1$.
Let $P$ be the vertices in $X$ with degree $k$ and $Q$ the vertices in $Y$ with degree $k$.

Now prove following statements:

1. $P$ cannot be empty.
2. $Q$ cannot be empty.
3. All edges starting in $Q$ must go to $P$.
4. There is a matching of $Q$ in the subgraph induced by $P\cup Q$.
5. Removing the edges of this matching produces a smaller counterexample for the claim. This final contradiction shows that no such counterexample can exist.

Proof of item 2 (assuming we already proved that $P$ is not empty):
Suppose $Q$ is empty. Now we remove one single edge $px$ that has an endpoint $p$ in $P$. The remaining graph still fulfills the degree conditions (the degree of the vertices in $Q$ can only be lower, the degree of the vertices in $P$ are unchanged, except the degree of $p$, that is now $k-1$, and because $Q$ was empty all neighbours of $p$ have degree at most $k-1$). But $X$ and $Y$ are still the same, so $G$ was not the smallest counterexample. Contradiction.

Comment: why do the degree conditions still hold on S(union)N(S)? the condition states that for some (a,b) in E(take a in S and b in N(S)) the degree of a in G is bigger than the degree of b in G, but the degree of b in the subgraph (N(S) union S) is not necessarily  equal to it's degree in G, that is b in N(S) can have vertices adjacent to it not in S.

Comment: All neighbours of $a$ are in $N(S)$, so the degree of $a$ cannot change. The degree of $b$ can only get smaller.

Comment: got it, can you help me with the proof of the lemma, i got stuck proving that Q is not empty

Comment: Added proof of item 2.